# Mongo month schema validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to validate if user select 2(FEB) for month then he should not enter dayOfMonth <= 28 only

How to validate

my schema is like bellow

```
date: {
    months: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: [validatorMonths, 'allowed session values are * and 0 to 11']
    },
    dayOfMonth: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: [validatorDayOfMonth, 'allowed day of month values are * and 1 to 31']
    } }

function validatorDayOfMonth(v) {
    return ((v == '*') || (v >= 1 && v <= 31)); };

function validatorMonths(v) {
    return ((v == '*') || (v >= 0 && v <= 11)); };
```

Comment: What validation/orm framework are you using

Comment: I am using Mongoose orm frame work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to check if the date returned is equal to the date provided:

```
function validatorDayOfMonth(v) {
  // Obviously replace the year with the correct value to account for leap years.
  // Within a validation function `this` refers to the root document being validated.
  return ((v === '*') || new Date(2015, this.date.months, v).getDate() === v);
};
```

This works because the Date constructor will automatically correct extra days/months to the appropriate date.

```
new Date(2015, 1, 29).getDate() // 1
```

Or you could use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) to do the same thing (although that may be overkill).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to take advantage of mongooose middleware for validate. It allows you to hook an event that you can call presave and access the entire schema http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate

you could do something like

```
doc.pre('save', function(next) {
    if(this.months === "2") {
        this.days <= 28 && this.days >= 1 ? next() : next("Error message");
    else {
        this.days <= 31 && this.days >= 1 ? next() : next("Error message");
}
```

Comment: What if the user selects June 31?

Comment: Only following requirement from post that states month 2 must be between 1 and 28. Even that requirement is not worded very well.